# What i = 1, 23 ;means.

Tags: c, compiler-construction

This funny thing happened when I make a mistake .

I what write :

`int i;`
`i = 1;`

but it is

`int i ;i = 1 ,23;`(I guess sometime I click the middle button of my mouse) .

Then I compiled the program by gcc and it went through without any warning or error!

And after I notice that  . I  try `int i = 1,23;` , and now the compile give a error:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

So ,Why the first time compile suceessful ?

And why it give me a error the second time?

What exactly  ", 23" means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, [initialization is not assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217839/is-there-a-difference-between-initializing-a-variable-and-assigning-it-a-value-i).

Comment: @H2CO3 What the first link mean? I go and only see **You see it used in for loop statements, but it's legal syntax anywhere. What uses have you found for it elsewhere, if any?**

Comment: @LidongGuo: You have to read the answers.

Comment: @LidongGuo You run into the comma operator. `i = 1, 23` is the same as `(i = 1)` since the expression `23` has no side effects.

Comment: @H2CO3 Nope .I print i and i is 1 not 23!

Comment: If it helps, the precedence of `=` over `,` is the source of relatively many mistakes (among those foolish enough to use the comma operator at all): http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/12/18/zlib-one-comma-misused