# Why the Output is 15 15 instead of 15 20?

Tags: c, static

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print();

int main(){ 

    print();    
    print();    
    return 0;    
}

void print(){

    static int x;    
    x=10;    
    x+=5;    
    printf("%d\t",x);

}
```

Output 15 15

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: @Blorgbeard can you please tell the output?

Comment: What he means is: SO has nice **markdown** to properly format source code. You want to turn to the help center to learn such things **prior** posting code here. As an example, see how the two lines in my answer are formatted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "static" mean in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Comment: The `static` variables are initialized only once.

Answer (score 4):

You have code that says:

```
 x = 10;
 x = 15;
```

and that then prints x.

Then you call that function two times.

Why again do you think that the second print should result in a different outcome; compared to the first one?!

You see, you start by assigning: 10. Plus 5. Why should that ever result in 20?

Hint - try changing your code to:

```
static int x = 10;
x += 5;
```

Long story short: re-**assigning** is not the same thing as re-**initializing**!

Comment: as x is static it should first print 15 and then accordingly as x is static it should print 20 or not?

Comment: See my updated answer. The point is: you are not "re-initializing". You are re-assigning. That is not the same thing. You know, you expect that `x = x + 5` gives x a new value; but then you expect that `x = 10` does not have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Here `static` variable declared(initialized) as `x`, then value assigned every time `10` not initialize.

So, output of your program `15` and `15` displayed.

initialization and assignment both are different. please read this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217839/is-there-a-difference-between-initializing-a-variable-and-assigning-it-a-value-i).

I hope this will help you and make your doubt clear.

Comment: it is static so x won't be re initialized again and again

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj 're-initialize' and 're-assign' are different things.

Comment: Can you explain in a simpler way?

Comment: @M.S Chaudhari but my compiler i.e Dev C++ gave as 15 15

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj same o/p 15 20

Comment: @M.S Chaudhari can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused with Reassigning and Re-intializing of static variable. You must have learnt somewhere that static variable dosn't re-initialize itself whenever the function gets called. Hence you are expecting answer 15 & 20.

But the thing is that you are re-assigning the value of x with 10 each and every time. If you modify your code like following then you can achieve what you've expected.

```
static int x=10;
x+=5;
```

Here, x gets initialized with 10 first time only. After that, for each and every function call, it will get incremented by 5 only.

Hope this will help and make your doubt clear.

Comment: Thanks I got it now

Comment: You're welcome. Voting helpful answer is always acceptable.