# Difference between ways of using malloc

Tags: c, malloc

What's the difference between 1 and 2?

1. ```
   int *p;
   p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
   ```
2. ```
   int *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
   ```

The way I first learned it is number 1, but I've seen someone do it number 2.
Is number 1 and 2 the same thing? I'm assuming it is, but
I'm confused because I don't understand why number 2 is

```
int *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

not

```
int p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

The way he used it was for array. Later in the code, he used p to save some desired values.

Like this.

```
p[0] = i;
p[1] = j;
```

Comment: You're allocating a pointer, so the type must be `int *p` in all cases.  That allows you to use `p[0]` etc too.  The one-liner is generally the better way to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) are the same which are used to initialize pointer with memory allocation.

I think you're confused with the way to initialize pointer, not how to use `malloc()`. Take a look on some articles about "Initialize pointer" like [this one](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20initialize%20a,address%20of%20the%20variable%20number%20.).

```c
int number = 88;     // An int variable with a value
int * pNumber;       // Declare a pointer variable called pNumber pointing to an int (or int pointer)
pNumber = &number;   // Assign the address of the variable number to pointer pNumber
 
int * pAnother = &number; // Declare another int pointer and init to address of the variable number
```

---

```c
int p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

This way is not correct to declare a pointer, in this case, `p` is just an integer variable, not a pointer that points to an integer variable.

Comment: *(1) and (2) are the same which are used to initialize pointer with memory allocation.* Not quite true. Initialization and assignment are not the same in C.  `int *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` *initializes* `p` with the value returned by `malloc()`, but `int *p; p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` *assigns* the value returned by `malloc()` to `p`.  That won't make any difference here, but initialization is not the same as assignment, and there are numerous constructs where it does matter.

Comment: See [**Is there a difference between initializing a variable and assigning it a value immediately after declaration?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217839/is-there-a-difference-between-initializing-a-variable-and-assigning-it-a-value-i) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between 1 and 2?

1 and 2 do the same thing. The compiler should produce exactly the same code. They both *declare* a variable `p` of type `int *` and then *initialize* `p` with the pointer returned from `malloc`.

It's `int *p = ...` because `int *` is the type. The variable is `p`. It is declaring the variable `p` as the type `int *` and then assigning to `p`.

The difference is that 2 does it in a single statement. This is preferable because it ensures the variable is initialized, and it makes it easier to see that the variable is initialized. Uninitialized variables contain garbage and are a common source of errors. It's usually a good idea to initialize every variable immediately, even if it's to `0` or `NULL`.

You will often see code which declares and initializes variables separately; sometimes all the variables are declared at the top of each function. This is an old style from way back when C required you to declare all your variables at the start of a function. This is no longer an issue. You can declare variables as needed now.